# Does any one know how to solve the following equation?

Tags: physics

When I reading this paper http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1976ApJ...209..214B&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf
I try to solve eq(49) numerically, it seems a fokker-planck equation, I find finite difference method doesn't work, it's unstable.
Does any one know how to solve it?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a homework answering service.

Comment: It is also not clear from your question alone what if anything this has to do with programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

[computational science stack exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) is where you can ask and hope for an answer. Or you could try its [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) cousin. The equation, you quote, is integro-differential equation, fairly non-linear... Fokker-Plank looking equation. Definitely not the typical Fokker-Plank.

What you can try is to discretize the space part of the function `g(x,t)`  using finite differences or finite-elements. After all, `0 < x < x_max` and you have boundary conditions. You also have to discretize the corresponding integration. So maybe finite elements might be more appropriate? Finite elements means you can write g(x, t) as a series of a well chosen basis of compactly supported simple enough functions Bj(x) : j = 1...N in the interval `[0, x_max]`

```
g(x,t) = sum_j=1:N  gj(t)*Bj(x)
```

That will turn your function into a (large) vector `gj(t) = g(x_j, t),   for j = 1, 1, ...., N`. As a result, you will obtain a non-linear system of ODEs

```
dgj(t)/dt = Qj(g1(t), g2(t), ..., gN(t))
j = 1 ... N
```

After that use something like Runge-Kutta to integrate numerically the ODE system.